# how do you embed a single pen on your website from codepen.io?

Tags: javascript, api, twitter, codepen

**Question:**
Is there any read up online where i can find out how to embed an interactive pen on my website from codepen.io?

**Example:** ( *like how it [works for Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets)* )

[image]
**NOTE:**
What am most interested in is embedding the following section of a *"pen"* on my website.

[image]

What i would like is for visitors to *like* or *comment* on a project on the fly.

**Assumption:**

Am assuming codepen.io has some sort of way to make it easy OR probably an API for this.

Comment: https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/features/embedded-pens/
 and 
https://codepen.io/embeds

Comment: @Andrey thanks but that is not what am interested in. I just need that part where you have the _watched_,  _comment_ and _like_ buttons. Some thing similar to when your go to the home page of your codepen account. i.e link here https://codepen.io/theAccountant/#